# Reading and Editing Video File Metadata in .NET

Tags: .net, avi

I'm writing an application in .net that will organise my video library. Windows Media Center reads the video metadata and displays the video title etc. I'd like to be able to read and edit this information using my .net application (I can do batch operations, apply rules based on folder names etc.).

I have researched this and it would seem that a 3rd party library is required but most of the information i've found seems to apply to MP3's and other audio formats. I would like to know if anyone can suggest any free libraries that would allow me to read and edit video file metadata? I'd also be interested to know if it is actually possible to do this without a 3rd party library.

Cheers

Stephen